# My Admanager account only showing Non-progmattic and Unfilled

Tags: google-ad-manager, ad-management

My All the revenue and impression are Showing in Non-programmatic channel dashboard and all the impression showing unfilled.. ( i am attaching screenshot )..

[Admanager account screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9oI2.jpg)

[Unfilled section screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWIVF.jpg)
[Approved by MA digimedia screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/922gQ.jpg)

even the ads are properly  displaying on my website...

my account approved by third party parent company Yomdigi media ( managed account ) 80/20 revenue share

Can you please help me what's the problem.. and any more details if need i can share .. please solve it

i tried creating the 2-3 new ad units but still the impression are unfilled and showing in Non-programmatic dashboard..

is this the parent company problem which they restricted programattic channel ads or my account ads unit configuration problem ??